# ¿Por qué se pude assignar una estructura, clase o enumeración con una lista de inicialización después de que fue declarada pero no una arreglo?

Tags: c++

Es un poco confusa la pregunta pero pongo código para darme a entender.

en c++ se puede utilizar aggregate initialization para inicializar lo que el
estandar define como un aggregate (un arreglo es un aggregate y también lo son
los struct y las class en algunos casos).

la cosa es que es completamente válido hacer:

```
int array[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

pero lo siguiente da un error de compilación:

```
int array[5];
array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

Pero si por ejemplo defino la siguiente estructura

```
struct View {
public:
    int array[5];
};
```

ahora es completamente válido hacer

```
View v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

y hacer

```
View v;
v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

Alguien sabe cual es la razón (de ser posible donde lo especifica el estándar) por la que un arreglo una vez que fue declarado no puede ser inicializado de esta manera pero por que no ocurre lo mismo con una estructura, una clase o una enumeración?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La respuesta de peregring-lk es correcta pero no explica el motivo de tales restricciones.

La respuesta sencilla es que una estructura o clase implementa por defecto una serie de constructores y de sobrecargas del operador de asignación que permiten realizar operaciones complejas, mientras que un array carece de ellos. Al no disponer el array de estas facilidades únicamente soportará instrucciones sencillas.

La única excepción para los arrays la encuentras en la inicialización. Pero no cualquier inicialización. La inicialización de un array tiene que hacerse con elementos conocidos en tiempo de compilación. Esto permite que el compilador convierta la lista de inicialización (o lo que se use para inicializarlo) en una serie de valores fijos en memoria... Y todo esto en tiempo de compilación... Si revisas el código fuente no verás tal lista de inicialización sino únicamente una ristra de valores.

Comment: Me suena bastante lógico la parte del operador de asignación, de hecho justo analizaba la posibilidad de escribir, v {1,2,3,4,5}; (sin operador igual) pero eso es error de compilacion a diferencia de View v {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; que si es válido.

Comment: Aunque dispusiera de "operador de asignación", dicho "operador de asignación" estaría definido para objetos array no constantes, y los arrays nunca lo son, así que "dicho operador de asignación" nunca podría ser llamado. Y lo que has dicho de que los elementos del array deben ser expresiones constantes (conocidos en tiempo de compilación), no es cierto.

Answer (score 3):

> #### 8.3.4 Arrays [dcl.array]
>
> *5* [*Note:* [...]. Objects of array types cannot be modified [...]]

Es decir, objetos de tipo *array* no son modificables. Y además:

> #### Assignment and compound assignment operators [expr.ass]
>
> *1* [...] All require a modifiable lvalue as their left operand and return an lvalue referring to the left operand.

Es decir, que si el operador de asignación requiere un *lvalue* modificable como operando izquierdo, y los *arrays* son siempre constantes, se entiende que un *array* nunca es un *lvalue* modificable; aunque no he llegado a encontrar en el estándar nada que diga exáctamente: **un array es un lvalue no modificable**.

Answer (score 0):

Otra razón fundamental es que inicializar el array no genera "codigo executable" (.text segment en ensamblador) sino "memoria inicializada" (.data segment o .rodata segment en ensamblador).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment